# Building history database using Google Forms and Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a particular need to build a database of Google Form submitted records. Dats is submitted each month. The issue is that I need the Google Form to pre-populate with the data from the last submission. The only way this can be done (unless someone can tell me otherwise) is to enable 'edit' on submitted data. In this way the user can change what is needed and re-submit. However, this will overwrite the existing row with the new data and I have then lost the data that was there before.

So I need to use Google Apps Script to 'copy' any row that is added or changed to another sheet, thereby building up a history of the data over time (the full year). The trigger, I think, would be upon change of the 'Period' cell which contains the month the data applies to. So this is what should happen:

User 1 enters data via the form for the first time in January. The created row is automatically copied to the 'History' sheet. In February, User 1 opens the form and is presented with all the data submitted in January. Changes are made if necessary and the month field changed from January to Fenruary. The script acts upon the change from January to February and copies the row to the 'History' sheet to the next available row (append).

This process is the same for all the users.

I am looking for the code that will be triggered upon change to copy the changed row to the History sheet, appending the entire row to the end of the sheet.

Thanks in anticipation...

Comment: to make on-topic show at least attempts.

Comment: If you could have the Form save each submission to a different spreadsheet or sheet tab in the same spreadsheet starting at the beginning of the month would that work?  There is an Add-on that will copy data to a different spreadsheet of your choice on each Form submission.  You would need to change the settings at the beginning of each month.  [Link to Add-on for Forms](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-director-for-forms/bjlicikmbfbjckkgemmiddonmigijpbj?authuser=0)